# How to know which JS script manipulated certain elements of the DOM using Firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am inspecting a website, which has tons of JS files loaded from several servers along with jQuery. Number of js files is really big. Some are within the regular scripts tags. Others are loaded dynamically via ajax.

I am interested in certain elements of the DOM which are manipulated because of some js file. I see the dynamic loaded elements in firebug. I needed to know exactly which JS script creates/updates them.
I searched the js files for the classes and the IDs of the elements,so I can have some clue about which js file affects them,  but I found nothing.

**Is there any direct way using Firebug to know exactly which JS file manipulates certain DOM elements?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not in a direct way.

- Use [EventBug](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/eventbug-alpha-released/) addon
- Then search by the function signature in your script panel to drill down to the js file

Hope this helps!

Comment: EventBug is not compatible with firefox 4 and higher. solution didn't work out.

Comment: Their latest is compatible with FF5: http://getfirebug.com/releases/eventbug/1.5/eventbug-0.1b9.xpi. In fact, if you look into it, its marked compatible till FF 7.1!

Comment: thats what i see in the events tab => click { return typeo... arguments) : b; }  
function (a) {
return typeof f != "undefined" && (!a || f.event.triggered !== a.type) ? f.event.handle.apply(k.elem, arguments) : b;
}.. I found the event, but still I don't know how to relate it to the js file

Comment: Its hard to tell, but taking a guess, it looks like a jQuery or some other library's click handler. Search for that and put a breakpoint there. Once you hit it, you can look at the Call Stack (in Script Panel) to see where it originated from.

Comment: **Search for that and put a breakpoint there** <= how to search it? have tried several ways, but none works.. how to search it?.. its a jQuery click handler by the way.

Comment: Have you tried the search box at top-right of script panel? That will let you search across all script files (make sure you've checked Multiple Files Options)

Comment: yes I tried it of course..its the only search box I got anyway.. but it finds nothing.. any ideas?

Comment: Can you search in files then via some tool (like Notepad++'s Search in Files)?

Comment: @Mrchief let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1227/discussion-between-ahmad-farouk-and-mrchief)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go to Script tab in firebug, then look at the toolbar right below the script tab you can select all the javascript files included on the page.

If you have an idea which file it is coming from then select that file and then look through the code and set break points on functions you think the event is coming from by clicking on the respective line number, then refresh the page and perform the event that calls the javascript.

You might have to put in a few before you narrow it down, but the break points will make it alot easier to tell which functions are being called for which events.

Comment: I need to know what is the script first before I inspect it :)